# Is there a way to utilize this scanner's full bed?

Tags: scanner

I have a CanoScan 8800F that's not scanning the full bed which measures 8.75" x 12". It seems to max out at the LTR (upper left) and A4 (bottom right) markers shown in below pic, causing whatever exceeds those markers to be cut off. My previous Canon scanner did the same thing. Is there a way to utilize the entire width and length of the bed? After all, there is glass there, so it seems like the scanner should be able to scan beyond the limits of LTR/A4.

[image]

Comment: Short answer, No.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the driver supports it.

The extra glass can be there for many reasons without giving any ability to use it for scanning.

It could be because of cost savings from shared components, or for allowances in differing manufacturing processes, or any of a number of other reasons.

So, look in the settings available in the driver, and if there are settings allowing the extra space, great, but if there isn't, sorry.